# AS3 .name attribute not working for a library symbol

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm having a symbol in the library that's exported for ActionScript to be added later.

A Loop is adding them sequentially, but I want to add a Mouse Event Listener to them and have them call another function when clicked, so I tried linking a .name attribute to them, but it is not working though the e.target.name , only working inside the loop :( , and I tried lots of things. What should I do ?? Thank you :)

```
    function CreateMenuPagesButtons(): void {

for (var i: uint = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {
    var menu_btn: MenuButton = new MenuButton;
    menu_btn.page_number.text = String(i + 1);
    menu_btn.name = (i + 1).toString();
    menu_btn.x = i * 50;
    menu_btn.page_number.mouseEnabled = false;
    MenuPagesButtons_Container.addChild(menu_btn);
}

    stage.addChild(MenuPagesButtons_Container);

    MenuPagesButtons_Container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, movetoTargetMenuPage);

function movetoTargetMenuPage(e: MouseEvent): void {
    var targetPage:String = e.target.name;
    trace(targetPage);
```

The trace function if inside the loop, gives correct names: 1 , 2 , 3, while the other one at the last line in the code as shown, gives the name of the instance set through the properties tab.. and if no name is given there, it will give "Instance110" - "Instance115" - etc..

Comment: Try to add `mouseChildren = false` property: `menu_btn.mouseChildren = false;`

Comment: Setting mouseChildren to false will actually disable all click-ability of children.. tried it and didn't work sorry :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got it fixed :D :D :D

Let me tell you how in case someone else had the same problem.

the (e.target.name) was referring to the clicked single button inside the over all symbol, rather than referring to the symbol from top level, so I changed it to (e.target.parent.name) and it worked.. Yayyy :D Thanks All :)

Answer (score -1):

This is so, because you add listener to `MenuPagesButtons_Container`, which means that `e.target` IS **`MenuPagesButtons_Container`**. If you want to get which button is clicked, you **must** add listeners to each button:

```
for (...) {
    menu_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, movetoTargetMenuPage);
```

Then it will work.

Comment: not correct, actually it is a good practice to reduce event listeners count by adding only one listener to a main container..

Comment: I don't understand how exactly he would understand what button he has clicked?

Comment: I always do add event listeners to the over all container, to increase efficiency , and all children will inherit it..

Comment: Oh I get the point, my fault. Anyways I would check children names and at the end - getObjectsUnderPoint :)